# Dissimilarity between shortest path trees

Tags: shortest-path

I am trying to find dissimilarity between shortest path tree of two nodes.

A sample undirected graph of 5 nodes with edges,edgeweight:

(4 1) 2
(1 2) 3
(3 2) 4
(1 3) 8
(4 3) 5
(2 4) 1
(5 4) 6
(1 5) 4
(2 5) 7

The Node names/Labels are:
Labels:
Node 1:s
Node 2:u
Node 3:x
Node 4:v
Node 5:y

I have computed the shortest path for the Nodes 1 and 2.

The shortest path for Node 1 is: {[1],[1 2],[1 3],[1 2 4],[1 5]}
The shortest path for Node 2 is: {[1],[2],[2 4 3],[ 2 4],[2 5]}

Given that shortest path can be represented as a vector of vertex labels T=[tk],k=1..N such that tk is the label of the parent of vertex k with a symbol 0 to indicate the root.
I need to find dissimilarity ie., the number of places where corresponding labels in T1 and T2 do not match.

Can any one be able to help me with this?

I am confused about the representation of T as a vector of vertex labels.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector T is a vector containing the parent labels of each node. For your sample, T1 would look like [0,0,0,2,0], indicating that, in order to get to 4, you have to follow the path to node 2 and then take a link to 4.

This is a rather simple way of representing your paths. If you need to find the differences between both vectors, you could compare them elementwise or do a xor between both vectors. If you take that difference, the differences you'll find are the nodes that have different parents.

Comment: Thank you so much. So just to make myself sure for Node T1 the vector is [0,0,0,2,0] and for node T2 it is[1,0,0,4,0,0] and so the number of places where T1 and T2 do not match is 2.
Also,could you also tell me if my understanding is correct if I need to find the number of edges the two trees do not share?
The formula would be (Number of vertices-1)-(Number of Edges the trees share)
So here it should be Number of Edges the trees share is 1,ie the edge [2 4]
Hence, the number of edges the tree do not share is 4-1=3.
Is this correct?
Thank you once again for your time and patience.

Comment: The vector for T2 seems to be [0,0,4,0,0], based on your {} solution. The vectors differ for 2 elements as the paths to 3 and 4 are not the same starting at the different roots. To reach 3 from 1, your path has length=1 while it is 2 in the other case.

Comment: To calculate the number of differences, you should replace all 0's in your vector with the root (so you get [1,1,1,2,1] and [2,2,4,2,2]) and then look at how many similarities you have. You only have the edge [2 4] in both of them so your answer should be '1 edge in common'. The number of edges that are different depends on your definition (e.g. do you count [1 3] and [2 3] as 1 or 2 different edges)

Comment: Each shortest path tree T has V-1 edges. If they have 1 in common, then each of them has V-2 edges the other doesn't have. If you count difference as two then you have an edge difference of 2V-4. If you count them as one, it's only V-2. Both interpretations are valid and you decide which one to use.

Comment: oh okay.Thank you once again for clearing my doubts. I am considering them as two for now. I am going to use for calculating the hierarchical clustering of the trees. Could you explain how the vector will be represented in the case if we consider them as one edge.